# angular : serialize an array of files to send to symfony backend

Tags: javascript, angular, symfony, serialization, form-data

I have an array of files and I want to send it to the backend Symfony.
I have a variable pdfs :

```
pdfs:File[] = [];
```

and I fill it inside onchange event of input file tag :

```
  getFiles(pdfs) {
    if (!pdfs) { return; }    
    let error = false;    
    for(let i = 0; i < pdfs.length; i++){
       if (pdfs[i].type.match(/application\/pdf/) == null)
         error = true;
       }
       if (pdfs[i].size > 5000000) {
         error = true;
       }
    }
    if(error){
      return;
    }

    this.pdfs.push.apply(this.pdfs, pdfs);
  }
```

I need to do that because the user can delete and add files from the UI, and FileList is read-only, so I had to put the files into an array so I can delete and add them, this is the UI :

[image]

and this the save function that send the API:

```
  save(form) {
    if (form.valid) {
      const componentData = new FormData();
      componentData.append('associatedFiles', JSON.stringify(this.pdfs));

      this.componentApiService.addComponent(componentData).subscribe((resp) => {
         console.log(resp);
      });
    }
  }
```

I used JSON.stringfy but the data received is an array of empty objects.

any idea how to do this please ?

Comment: JSON. Stringify({'PDFs':this.pdfs} )?

Comment: It's the same, just an object contain an object with empty arrays now

Comment: Okay that means the pdfs content is not stringifialbe.  You'll need to deal with it as a blob.  Here's the run down on that from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File